# What do you call individual "subcakes" of a multi-layered cake?

Tags: word-request

What do you call those flat pieces of baked dough with cream in between that make up a cake? In Russian, we would say "корж" (singular)

[image]

Comment: I DV'd because you already had an obvious answer ("layer") in your title and didn't explain why that word wouldn't work. You also didn't indicate any research (for example, looking up "корж" in a Russian-English dictionary). If you amend the question, I'd be happy to change my vote.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan -  `корж` just means 'cake'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I wonder why he said it meant the flat pieces inside, then.

Comment: I note that the stuff inbetween is called "frosting" in English.  Or else we usually put different stuff between the layers

Comment: Google image search really helps in such a situation.

Comment: @Mary - The stuff on the outside is _frosting_ in America and _icing_ in the UK. Buttercream is usually used to stick the layers together (butter with powdered sugar beaten into it).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan because it's not how the word is actually used. Nobody in Russia would use "корж" to refer to the whole cake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those would be called "cake layers".

For example, this article on [How to Build a Layered Cake](https://www.completelydelicious.com/how-to-build-a-layered-cake/) includes the following instructions:

> To assemble, first place a cooled/chilled **cake layer** top side-down on a cardboard round

Another article advises on [how to get perfect flat **cake layers**](https://preppykitchen.com/how-to-get-perfect-flat-cake-layers/).

Answer (score 3):

They are called **layers**. That type of cake is often called a **layer cake**. The material of the layers, separated by creamy stuff, is called 'cake', which can be used an an uncountable or mass noun.

Cake is:

> a sweet food made from flour, eggs, fat, and sugar mixed together and
> baked

[Cake (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cake)

[image]

More generally, a layer is:

> a level of material ... that is different from the material above or below it

[Layer (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/layer)

Answer (score 2):

They are *tiers*:

[AHD *tier*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tier)
n.

1. One of a series of rows placed one above another: a stadium with four tiers of seats.
2. A rank or class.
   tr. & intr.v. tiered, tier·ing, tiers
   To arrange (something) into or rise in tiers: **tier a wedding cake**; balconies that tier upward.

(as Esther points out, tiered cakes usually have smaller upper layers.)

Or just *layers*.

[AHD *layer*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=layer)

a. A single thickness of a material covering a surface or forming an overlying part or segment: a layer of dust on the windowsill; **a cake with four layers**.

Comment: "tiers" would generally be when each layer is smaller in diameter than the one above it; "layers" would be the kind of cake in the OP

Comment: Yes, you're right, searching on images shows tiered cakes having successive layers of decreasing diameters.